# Crontab revision control?

Tags: version-control, cron

I've got a few dozen Linux machines running `cron` and I'd like to put the crontabs in some sort of revision control system.  For source control I use Mercurial (`hg`), so that'd be ideal, but if there's some other system that is better suited to this task I'd consider it.

One aspect which is specific to my situation is that all the crontabs belong to a common user (not a real person, but a placeholder "services" login).  I'd like the revision history to include the actual author of each change, rather than the special account where the cron jobs actually run.

Comment: Have you considered using /etc/crontab.d? You could keep crontab templates in version control, with placeholers for user and anything else that may vary between systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

crontab -l dumps your crontab to standard output, which you could redirect to a file.  You could have a job (in cron, naturally) to redirect this to a file which is then diffed, and pushed to source control as necessary.

Comment: Yes but then there's no room for commit comments nor author attribution.

Comment: This answer is closest to what we ended up doing.  We just skip the automatic commit to VCS, because we want the author and comment fields to be correct.  So we issue warning emails if people forget to check in their changes to the repository.  It works kind of OK, but could still stand improvement.

Answer (score 2):

http://joey.kitenet.net/code/etckeeper/ ?

From that site:

> etckeeper is a collection of tools to let /etc be stored in a git, mercurial, darcs, or bzr repository. It hooks into apt (and other package managers including yum and pacman-g2) to automatically commit changes made to /etc during package upgrades. It tracks file metadata that revison control systems do not normally support, but that is important for /etc, such as the permissions of `/etc/shadow`. It's quite modular and configurable, while also being simple to use if you understand the basics of working with revision control.

Comment: This is kind of all right, but not really a full solution for my needs.  A curiosity, I'd say, but so far I've ended up implementing something myself (nothing complex enough to be worth posting code for...basically just a monitoring script which checks `crontab -l` output against a VCS repo.

Answer (score 0):

If the linux system follows the LFS (linux filesystem standard, IIRC), then /etc should only contain config files. I had pretty good experience by importing the whole of /etc into CVS.

The only problem is that only root could commit changes, so it was a bit hard to see who broke something. This can be solved by assigning every admin a 3 letter short name and setting up the rule that each commit must start with this name.